# Difference between stable marriage problem and assignment problem

Tags: assignment-problem

What is the difference between the [stable marriage problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stable_marriage_problem) and an [assignment problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Assignment_problem)? Both refer to a [matching problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marriage_problem) in general but what is their specific difference?
I can see clear differences in the implementation but do not see any related to the motivation. Both aim at assigning a man to a female -  both approaches take into account preferences.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The main difference is the optimization goal.

In classical assignement problem, there is a fitness/cost function to maximize/minimize. Each assignement possibility has a weight and you only sum up all these weights to get the best global result. Only the overall result matters even if it means some individual assignements have a very bad fitness/cost.

In the stable marriage problem, it is the opposite. You do not care about the overall optimality. You just want to guarantee that it does not exist a "male" and a "female" that would both be "happier" together rather than with their assigned partner.

The idea behind the word "stable" is that if such a couple exists, they will tend to get together breaking your initial assignement.

An exemple:
two "males" A and B and two "females" C and D

```
A loves hardly C (weight 10) and not D (weight 1)
B loves a little more C (weight 3) than D (weight 2)
C loves a little more B (weight 3) than A (weight 2)
D loves hardly B (weight 10) and not A (weight 1)
```

In assignement problem, you clearly put A&C and B&D to get a fitness score of 24. But this is not a stable marriage as B and C would rather like to be together. A&D and B&C is a stable marriage but only has a fitness score of 8.

Comment: Thank you! I guess I've been too long in the assignment problem because I understand preferences as weights. Hence, how can couples be assigned together as best as possible when a global optimum is not considered? How shall they know they are close when other pairings are not considered?
With stable you mean they get matched also by disregarding a global optimum?

Comment: I added an example. It is it clear with this ?

Comment: Thank you again! The wording stable is complicated here. An assignment problem will provide two pairing of a score of 12 (AC) and 12 (BD).
Why are two pairings with 2 (AD) and 6 (BC) seen as "stable"? Because their differences in weights are less marked (1+1=2 and 3+3=6 against 10+2 =12 and 10+12=12)?

Comment: Staying at women and men: What is the advantage of both problems over the other?
I guess I understood the concept now but to make a decision is now a bit difficult.

Comment: A&D and B&C is stable because even if A(D) would prefer to be with C(B), B&C are happy together and do not desire this change.

With the assignement result A&C and B&D, both B and C would prefer to be together => this is unstable.

Comment: About applications:
 
On a problematics of workers, schedule, buying... where you can evaluate the assignement with a unique metric (cost, time...), you are solving an assignement problem.

Stable marriage problem would instead solve problem where individual metric is important. It is perfect when you consider human beings, and the "marriage" gives a good visualization. You just prevent people from cheating with their marriage.

Comment: How to understand the individual metric?

As we're in the marriage problem which can be solved by an assignment problem and by the stable marriage problem, in both methods I utilize a metric (either being a weight or a rank)?

When I prevent people from cheating when perform the marriage problem, what do I gain by the assignment problem?

Comment: If for instance each man and woman gives you the weight of their assignement in money and you just don't care on what will happen next.

Comment: Though it might seem like a mind game but I would like to extend this thought: How are the preferences given when using the stable problem? There it has also to bef deined how to measure their preferences?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/88298/discussion-between-vince-and-ben).